# Unbold title and section labels for Beamer ppt

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I've got a strange issue where the title and frame/slide titles are all bolded and closer to the border of the slide, yet I did not command this. To help clarify my issue, I have attached a screenshot of what the output of my Beamer template was giving me (for a different talk) and what it's giving me now.

```
\documentclass[12pt,xcolor={table,dvipsnames},t]{beamer}
% \usetheme{Harris}
% \usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{ textcomp }
%\usepackage{ tipa }

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
```

```
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Overview}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
```

[image: Mysteriously bolded sections + title]

[image: Original output sample]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre] that reproduces the error instead of just code fragments. Please also show your .log file.

Comment: Unrelated: don't use `enumitem` with beamer, they are not compatible.